# iOS background location app terminated automatically after 15 or 17 hours later

Tags: ios, swift, background, location

I built my gps location app working on background mode.
But it was terminated after 15 or 17 hours later when the app entered background mode.
Here is my code.

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

[This is capability image of my app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJeBF.png)

Comment: So what's your question?  You want to find out why your app will be terminated after 15 or 17 hours?  Who knows!?  You are not telling how you are using your location data.

Comment: Hi, my app upload location data to backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are monitoring with the accuracy set to nearest 10 meters, the user can manually quit your app or the system can terminate you in the background for any reason (e.g. reclaiming RAM) and you will no longer receive updates until you relaunch. iOS will not relaunch you in the background when resources are available; your user has to do it explicitly.

If you use [significant change](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service) or [region monitoring (like geofencing)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions) events, you can be relaunched in the background by the system unless your users turn it off but this will obviously not guarantee an update every 10 meters.

There is no specific promise as to how long you can run in the background or that you will not be terminated by the system for reasons completely out of your control.

Comment: I didn't use any main thread while app was in background mode. Only called api to upload location info but app was terminated every 15~17 hours.